# IBM Worklight 6.0 application not working in Blackberry 7 Simulator

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-simulator

I have installed the Worklight 6.0 and Blackberry 7 SDK + Simulator. When I package and Launch to the Blackberry Simulator, Application is deployed to the simulator. But the app stuck with the IBM Logo[Splash screen].

I have deleted the app re-deployed and restarted the Simulator also.

App working in Ripple,

Suggest a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @Zaibis Question has been clearly explained that the app is not working in blackberry simulator and in the device as well

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse displaying an app in Ripple to actually running it on a device or simulator.

In Ripple you only load the web resources of the application, just like you would do if previewing it via Worklight Console.

When you run the app in a device or simulator, it has been packaged into its native shell.
Edit your question with the full steps you have taken, from creating the project in Eclipse to adding the environment, any changes you've made there, to setup Ripple with the app and finally running it.

Comment: I have followed the procedure given in the Worklight modules, Setting up worklight environment for Blackberry 6 and 7 also I followed the Previewing the application on blackberry. Java 32 bit and Blackberry Webworks SDK I have installed. In eclipse i have included the Blackberry 6 and 7 environment. After building I have used ripple to Package and Launch. App with default Worklight icon is deployed in device, when I launch the app Web Inspector is online alert i am getting but it stuck with splash screen. Thank you.